# Package is installed inside docker but actual command provide exception

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, ffmpeg, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use ffmpeg core package inside .net 6 dockerized project. I install ffmpeg core inside Dockerfile, reference actual package FFMpegCore inside solution but when I try to apply any of the commands from the ffmpeg core lib I'm getting error

> An error occurred trying to start process './ffmpeg' with working
> directory '/var/task'. No such file or directory

Docker build is done with no error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base
....
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
....
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

As per [ffmpeg core](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) docs in order to use ffmpeg I need to set its binary folder, so I add *ffmpeg.config.json*

```
{
  "BinaryFolder": "/var/task",
  "TemporaryFilesFolder": "/tmp"
}
```

Actual error is being thrown when I try to execute following command

> An error occurred trying to start process './ffmpeg' with working
> directory '/var/task'. No such file or directory

This is the place where error gets triggered

```
 using FFMpegCore;
 ...
 public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<string> Get()
        {    
             await FFMpegArguments
                   .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(myfile))
                   .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(outputStream), options => options
                      .WithVideoCodec("vp9")
                      .ForceFormat("webm"))
                      .ProcessAsynchronously();
             ...
        }    
    }
```

Update:
After changing `BinaryFolder` location to `/usr/bin` I'm getting following error

```
An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' with working directory '/var/task'. No such file or directory
```

Update #2
This is my complete Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AWSServerless.csproj", "AWSServerless/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AWSServerless/AWSServerless.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/AWSServerless"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AWSServerless.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish   

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev \
    && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

RUN dotnet publish "AWSServerless.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task

CMD ["AWSServerless::AWSServerless.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync"]
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it that the binary is in `/var/task` in `ffmpeg.config.json`, but `apt-get install -y ffmpeg` installs ffmpeg in `/usr/bin`. Change the `BinaryFolder` config value to that like this

```
{
  "BinaryFolder": "/usr/bin",
  "TemporaryFilesFolder": "/tmp"
}
```

You also need to install `ffmpeg` at a point in the Dockerfile where it'll end up in the final image. Right now you install it in the build/publish part of the Dockerfile which isn't used for the final image.

Try this instead

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base
# Install ffmpeg
RUN mkdir /ffmpeg && \
    cd /ffmpeg && \
    yum -y install tar xz && \
    curl https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz -o ffmpeg.tar.xz -s && \
    tar -xf ffmpeg.tar.xz && \
    mv ffmpeg-*-amd64-static/ffmpeg /usr/bin && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf ffmpeg

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AWSServerless.csproj", "AWSServerless/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AWSServerless/AWSServerless.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/AWSServerless"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AWSServerless.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish   
RUN dotnet publish "AWSServerless.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task

CMD ["AWSServerless::AWSServerless.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync"]
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

Comment: It does makes sense but now I'm getting this error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' with working directory

Comment: You haven't provided your entire Dockerfile. Are you sure that the step to install ffmpeg ends up in the final image? It looks like it still can't find the binary.

Comment: I updated the question with my complete Dockerfile

Comment: The install was in a wrong spot. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm getting in Step 2/15 .   /bin/sh: apt-get: command not found

Comment: I don't know the AWS lambda images. If apt-get doesn't work, you need to find out how to install ffmpeg on it.

Comment: I tried looking at it. The lambda image uses `yum` instead of `apt-get` but there doesn't seem to be an `ffmpeg` package available with yum as far as I can see.

Comment: @user1765862 I think I found a way to install it. It's not pretty, but it worked when I tried it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting '/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found' in the Step 2

Comment: @user1765862 Somehow my edit of the post got lost. I've made it again. Sorry about that.

Comment: will try in next couple of hours and I'll accept it if works. Thanks for all the effort